# can't install grunt locally

Tags: node.js, npm, gruntjs

The logs looks like this.

```
8 http fetch GET 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/gurnt 2232ms
9 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for gurnt@latest 404 Not Found: gurnt@latest
10 verbose stack Error: 404 Not Found: gurnt@latest


16 error code E404
17 error 404 Not Found: gurnt@latest
18 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice how the url says `gurnt` not `grunt`. I think this is just a typo. Try running `npm install grunt`